# How to write camera and gallery access permission on the Info.plist file

Tags: ios, xcode

After submission for review, I got this from Apple review:

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the camera and photos, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the camera and photos in the purpose string.

In my app, camera and gallery access is needed in various places like for uploading product images, sending images to chat, posting images in the news feed, and uploading profile photo.

Apple requires an explanation to why the camera and gallery are being accessed.
If I explain the use for uploading profile image, this is irrelevant if they upload a product and also needs another explanation if the user will send photos to chat.

So the question is how can I generalize the camera's purpose string in a way that it can cover all my camera usage given that the purpose string is only one.

Or is there a way to write a camera purpose string for each and every camera usage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @john we have to elaborate properly as they show the same message to the user on the permission popup.
I am using the below statement & app is accepted by AppStore

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Access to your camera is required to capture photos required for loan processing or your profile.</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To show your location on the map.</string>
```

Hope this will work!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have multiple purpose strings because Apple is not allowing you to customize the permission dialog.
You can just put what they are used for in one sentence, like "Need your permission to Photo Gallery for post or chat"

I got the same response the other day. My case is using the photo for feedback or a user avatar. So I just put all of them in that string

Hope this will help.

Comment: `Need your permission to Photo Gallery for post or chat` apple doesn't accept this. I  already tried it.